# Speeding up an iloc solution within a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following `DataFrame`:

```
dates = pd.date_range('20150101', periods=4)
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [5,10,3,4]}, index = dates)

df.loc[:,'B'] = 0
df.loc[:,'C'] = 0
df.iloc[0,1]  = 10
df.iloc[0,2]  = 3

print df

Out[69]:

             A   B  C
2015-01-01   5  10  3
2015-01-02  10   0  0
2015-01-03   3   0  0
2015-01-04   4   0  0
```

I want to implement the following logic for the columns `B` and `C`:

- `B(k+1) = B(k) - A(k+1)`
- `C(k+1) = B(k) + A(k+1)`

I can do this using the following code:

```
for i in range (1, df.shape[0]): 
        df.iloc[i,1] = df.iloc[i-1,1] - df.iloc[i,0] 
        df.iloc[i,2] = df.iloc[i-1,1] + df.iloc[i,0] 
print df
```

This gives:

```
             A   B   C
2015-01-01   5  10   3
2015-01-02  10   0  20
2015-01-03   3  -3   3
2015-01-04   4  -7   1
```

Which is the answer I'm looking for. The problem is when I apply this to a `DataFrame` with a large dataset it runs slow. Very slow. Is there a better way of achieving this?

Comment: in your result why is second 'B' `5` ? shouldn't it be `0` ? And why is second `C` 15 instead of `13` ?

Comment: Whoops! Sorry, my mistake. Have updated.

Comment: I changed the question slightly and added a toy solution...

Comment: I like this question because to do this in Excel or LibreOffice would be trivial, but it's not as obvious how to do it in Pandas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recursive things like this can be hard to vectorize.  [`numba`](http://numba.pydata.org/) usually handles them well - if you need to redistribute your code, [`cython`](http://cython.org/) may be a better choice as it produces regular c-extensions with no extra dependencies.

```
In [88]: import numba

In [89]: @numba.jit(nopython=True)
    ...: def logic(a, b, c):
    ...:     N = len(a)
    ...:     out = np.zeros((N, 2), dtype=np.int64)
    ...:     for i in range(N):
    ...:         if i == 0:
    ...:             out[i, 0] = b[i]
    ...:             out[i, 1] = c[i]
    ...:         else:
    ...:             out[i, 0] = out[i-1,0] - a[i]
    ...:             out[i, 1] = out[i-1,0] + a[i]
    ...:     return out

In [90]: logic(df.A.values, df.B.values, df.C.values)
Out[90]: 
array([[10,  3],
       [ 0, 20],
       [-3,  3],
       [-7,  1]], dtype=int64)

In [91]: df[['A','B']] = logic(df.A.values, df.B.values, df.C.values)
```

Edit:
As shown in the other answers, this problem can actually be vectorized, which you should probably use.

Comment: Yep. This is very cool! Solved my problem, as my actual logic was a bit more involved than that above. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

A trick to vectorize is to rewrite everything as cumsums.

```
In [11]: x = df["A"].shift(-1).cumsum().shift().fillna(0)

In [12]: x
Out[12]:
2015-01-01     0
2015-01-02    10
2015-01-03    13
2015-01-04    17
Name: A, dtype: float64

In [13]: df["B"].cumsum() - x
Out[13]:
2015-01-01    10
2015-01-02     0
2015-01-03    -3
2015-01-04    -7
dtype: float64

In [14]: df["B"].cumsum() - x + 2 * df["A"]
Out[14]:
2015-01-01    20
2015-01-02    20
2015-01-03     3
2015-01-04     1
dtype: float64
```

Note: The first value is a special case so you have to adjust that back to 3.

Answer (score 2):

A complete solution:

```
df1 = df[:1]
df['B'] = df['B'].shift().cumsum()[1:] - df['A'][1:].cumsum()
df[:1] = df1
df['C'] = df['B'].shift() + df['A']
df[:1] = df1
df

            A   B   C
2015-01-01  5   10  3
2015-01-02  10  0   20
2015-01-03  3   -3  3
2015-01-04  4   -7  1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the underlying arrays in numpy and get a much faster, simpler solution. Here we can get a 130x speedup.

```
dates = pd.date_range('20150101', periods=10000)
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : np.random.rand(10000)}, index = dates)

df.loc[:,'B'] = 0
df.loc[:,'C'] = 0
df.iloc[0,1]  = 10
df.iloc[0,2]  = 3
```

Old, slow, Pandas version:

```
%%time
for i in range (1, df.shape[0]): 
        df.iloc[i,1] = df.iloc[i-1,1] - df.iloc[i,0] 
        df.iloc[i,2] = df.iloc[i-1,1] + df.iloc[i,0]


CPU times: user 6.02 s, sys: 3.33 ms, total: 6.02 s
Wall time: 5.98 s
```

Better, fast, numpy version:

```
%%time
arr_a = df['A'].to_numpy()
arr_b = df['B'].to_numpy()
arr_c = df['C'].to_numpy()
for i in range(1, df.shape[0]):
    arr_b[i] = arr_b[i - 1] - arr_a[i]
    arr_c[i] = arr_b[i - 1] + arr_a[i]


CPU times: user 47.6 ms, sys: 23 µs, total: 47.6 ms
Wall time: 46 ms
```

The numpy arrays reference the original memory, so changing the numpy arrays modifies the dataframe as well.

Pandas indexing is ludicrously slow. They expect you to use vectorized operations, but for problems like this, it's difficult to get the 3 PhD's required to understand what set of groups, merges, and indexing Pandas would need. Pulling out the underlying arrays and doing the modifications directly is much simpler and faster.

Comment: "The numpy arrays reference the original memory, so changing the numpy arrays modifies the dataframe as well." This has not consistently been true for me. I would like to understand under what conditions it is reliable.

Answer (score 1):

Basically it is just your answer without the for loop:

```py
df['B'].iloc[1:] = df['B'].iloc[:-1].values - df['A'].iloc[1:].values
df['C'].iloc[1:] = df['B'].iloc[:-1].values + df['A'].iloc[1:].values
```

I don't know about performance issues, but i guess without the loop it will be faster.

Comment: This isn't quite right, but does seem very close (though that may just be due to the zeros in the dataset)...