# Faster way to do t-1 calculations in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a df with 250,000+ rows. I have a few fields which are dependent on t-1 values. This is a breeze to do in excel, but not sure what the most efficient way to do it in pandas is. Currently I set the t[0] value, then use a for loop to do the rest, but this is incredibly slow. Is there a faster way to do this?

Any help be greatly appreciated!

code below

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math
import datetime
from scipy.optimize import minimize

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Time': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    'Price': [44, 100, 40, 110, 77, 109, 65, 93, 89, 73]})

# Create Empty Columns
df[['Qty', 'Buy', 'Sell', 'Cost', 'Rev']] = pd.DataFrame([[0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00]], index=df.index)

# Initial Values
buy_price = 50
sell_price = 100

# Set Values at Time 0
df.at[0, 'Qty'] = 0
df.at[0, 'Buy'] = np.where(df.at[0, 'Price'] < buy_price, min(30 - df.at[0, 'Qty'], 10), 0)
df.at[0, 'Sell'] = np.where(df.at[0, 'Price'] > sell_price, min(df.at[0, 'Qty'], 10), 0)
df.at[0, 'Cost'] = df.at[0, 'Buy'] * df.at[0, 'Price']
df.at[0, 'Rev'] = df.at[0, 'Sell'] * df.at[0, 'Price']

# Set Remaining Values
for t in range(1, len(df)):
    df.at[t, 'Qty'] = df.at[t-1, 'Qty'] + df.at[t-1, 'Buy'] - df.at[t-1, 'Sell']
    df.at[t, 'Buy'] = np.where(df.at[t, 'Price'] < buy_price, min(30 - df.at[t, 'Qty'], 10), 0)
    df.at[t, 'Sell'] = np.where(df.at[t, 'Price'] > sell_price, min(df.at[t, 'Qty'], 10), 0)
    df.at[t, 'Cost'] = df.at[t, 'Buy'] * df.at[t, 'Price']
    df.at[t, 'Rev'] = df.at[t, 'Sell'] * df.at[t, 'Price']
```

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33184452/speeding-up-an-iloc-solution-within-a-pandas-dataframe) previous post, which was similar but I don't think cumsum() would work in this occasion as all 3 main fields (Qty, Buy, Sell) are interrelated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot cleaner approach will be to write a predicate which can store state and then call apply function once. 
Define predicate as shown below

```
class Predicate():
    def __init__(self):
        self.buy_price = 50
        self.sell_price = 100
        self.prev_qty = 0
        self.prev_buy_price = 0
        self.prev_sell_price = 0
    def __call__(self, x):
        x.Qty = self.prev_qty + self.prev_buy_price - self.prev_sell_price
        x.Buy = np.where(x.Price < buy_price, min(30 - x.Qty, 10), 0)
        x.Sell = np.where(x.Price > sell_price, min(x.Qty, 10), 0)
        x.Cost = x.Buy * x.Price
        x.Rev = x.Sell * x.Price
        self.prev_buy_price = x.Buy
        self.prev_qty = x.Qty
        self.prev_sell_price = x.Sell
        return x
```

And apply the predicate as

```
p = Predicate()
df.apply(p, axis=1)
```

Gives the following result

```
    Time    Price   Qty Buy Sell    Cost    Rev
0   0.0 44.0    10.0    10.0    0.0 440.0   0.0
1   1.0 100.0   20.0    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
2   2.0 40.0    20.0    10.0    0.0 400.0   0.0
3   3.0 110.0   30.0    0.0 10.0    0.0 1100.0
4   4.0 77.0    20.0    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
5   5.0 109.0   20.0    0.0 10.0    0.0 1090.0
6   6.0 65.0    10.0    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
7   7.0 93.0    10.0    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
8   8.0 89.0    10.0    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
9   9.0 73.0    10.0    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

Comment: Hi @abhilb, this is an amazing method!! thank you so much for your help. However i just had one question. the values at t[0] dont seem to line up, I added a print(x) line into the function and it appears as if the function runs over t[0] twice for some reason, which then results in the wrong starting point. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I wasn't aware of this problem. I saw the following in the documentation. Notes

In the current implementation apply calls func twice on the first column/row to decide whether it can take a fast or slow code path. This can lead to unexpected behavior if func has side-effects, as they will take effect twice for the first column/row.

Comment: ahh ok, makes sense. I've worked around this with an if statement in the function (prev_self.Time = x.Time then do ...), and its working perfectly. significantly faster than what I had before. really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

`pandas` Dataframes are not meant for looping over the rows. I suggest you take the take to learn thoroughly the uses and functions of it. In the mean while, this should help you with what you need (I did it on the fly, so let me know if there is a compiling error):

```
df['Qty'] = df['Qty'].shift() + df['Buy'].shift() - df['Sell'].shift()
df['Buy'] = df.apply(lambda x: 0 if x['Price'] >= buy_price else min(30 - X['Qty'], 10))
df['Sell'] = df.apply(lambda x: 0 if x['Price'] <= sell_price else min(x['Qty'], 10))
df['Cost'] = df['Buy'] * df['Price']
df['Rev'] = dft['Sell'] * df['Price']
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `cumsum` and `np.where` instead of `apply`:

```
df["Buy"]= np.where(df["Price"]<50, np.where((30 - df["Qty"]) > 10, 10, 30 - df["Qty"]), 0)
df["Sell"] = np.where(df["Price"]>100, np.where(df["Qty"] > 10, df["Qty"], 10), 0)
df["Qty"] = (df["Buy"].shift()-df["Sell"].shift()).cumsum()
df['Cost'] = df['Buy'] * df['Price']
df['Rev'] = df['Sell'] * df['Price']

print (df)
#
   Time  Price   Qty   Buy  Sell   Cost     Rev
0     0     44   NaN  10.0   0.0  440.0     0.0
1     1    100  10.0   0.0   0.0    0.0     0.0
2     2     40  10.0  10.0   0.0  400.0     0.0
3     3    110  20.0   0.0  10.0    0.0  1100.0
4     4     77  10.0   0.0   0.0    0.0     0.0
5     5    109  10.0   0.0  10.0    0.0  1090.0
6     6     65   0.0   0.0   0.0    0.0     0.0
7     7     93   0.0   0.0   0.0    0.0     0.0
8     8     89   0.0   0.0   0.0    0.0     0.0
9     9     73   0.0   0.0   0.0    0.0     0.0
```